# Creating a file uploading system in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, file-upload

In my `Django` application I intend to create a file uploading system which puts the user uploaded files in a `data` folder. In order to do this I followed online tutorials [Link 1](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html) [Link 2](http://nemesisdesign.net/blog/coding/django-private-file-upload-and-serving/) and coded a below simple application. But it is producing error

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data'

**Project Structure**

```
<project_name>
|--data
|--<app_name>
|--<project_name>
|--manage.py
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="custom-file">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" multiple required>
<label class="custom-file-label" for="fileupload">Choose files</label>
</div>
```

**view.py**

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def upload(request):
    files = request.FILES.getlist('fileupload')

    fs = FileSystemStorage(location="/data/upload/")

    for fl in files:
        fs.save(fl.name, fl)
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating multiple file upload should handle in the form.

Take a look at [Uploading multiple files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files)

In your `forms.py`

```
from django import forms

class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

In your `views.py`

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import FileFieldForm

class FileFieldView(FormView):
    form_class = FileFieldForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'  # Replace with your template.
    success_url = '...'  # Replace with your URL or reverse().

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                ...  # Do something with each file.
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: Whats missing in my above approach

Comment: One if you don't have write access to the directory it will show that error `chmod a+w path/to/dir` and the fs instance should be created outside the function take a look at the tutorial you mentioned http://nemesisdesign.net/blog/coding/django-private-file-upload-and-serving/